# How can I install python IDLE in Red Hat Enterprise Linux?

Tags: rhel, package-management

I'm new to RHEL and I use python as my programming language.

IDLE seems to me a good editor for my programs. In case of debian (which i used previously) I know how to install this. But, the package installer command **apt** doesn't work here.

Comment: What distribution are you using? There isn't any specific thing as "redhat" — there is Red Hat Enterprise Linux, and Fedora, which is sponsored by Red Hat.

Comment: I am using RHEL.Sorry,i forgot to mention that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just enter `yum install python3` at the console as this includes python libs and the editor.

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate questions here:

1. `Apt` analog for RedHat systems. If you use RedHat, CentOS or analog, it is `yum`. If it is Fedora, `yum` and `dnf` are usually present, with preference to the latter one.
2. IDLE presence. According to [this](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=53908), IDLE is available in python-tools, but first you should install `epel-release` package to reach EPEL repository. Exact package name is `python34-tools`, provided you need Python3.